# preg_match for MgmtEth0\/RSP1\/CPU0\/0/

Tags: php, preg-match

```
(preg_match('/^interface MgmtEth0\/RSP1\/CPU0\/0/', trim($val))
```

`interface MgmtEth0\/RSP1\/CPU0\/0/`
In this RSP0 is also present and at the end 0 or 1.

Comment: why do you use preg_match if you want to just check for equality?

Answer (score 0):

To match `0` or `1` at the end use:

```
preg_match('~^interface MgmtEth0/RSP1/CPU0/[01]$~', trim($val);
```

Here `[01]$` will match **0 or 1 at the end** of your input.